# Positive lookbehind doesn't work with plus

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm trying to select place after pattern word `<Art><dot><digits><dot>`

Code:

```
Art. 83.
xxx xxx xxx
Art. 3.
xxx xxx xxx
```

So far I tried this pattern, however  if add `+` for `\d` selection fails.. why?

> (?<=Art..\d\d.).

How can I select text after text with random digits length?

### Edit 1

Ok I need add new line for every text with after text pattern `Art. <digits length unknown>.`

Input

```
Art. 3.
xxx xxx xxx
```

Output

```
Art. 3.

xxx xxx xxx
```

### Edit 2

I am looking solution for language `JAVA` / `Android` / parser in `Notepad++`

Comment: Most versions of regex require lookarounds have to be a fixed length. Can you clarify what you want to match..sometimes you can avoid lookarounds and use matching groups to select what you want.

Comment: Your edit helped, thanks. What language are you writing in also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using look behind, not lookahead, which has limitations in most implementations. From http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

> The bad news is that most regex flavors do not allow you to use just any regex inside a lookbehind, because they cannot apply a regular expression backwards. The regular expression engine needs to be able to figure out how many characters to step back before checking the lookbehind. When evaluating the lookbehind, the regex engine determines the length of the regex inside the lookbehind, steps back that many characters in the subject string, and then applies the regex inside the lookbehind from left to right just as it would with a normal regex.

In your case, maybe you can use an expression that matches text and uses the match in the replacement. For example, in Java:

```
String original = "Art. 3.\nxxx xxx xxx";
String replaced = original.replaceAll("Art\\. \\d+\\.", "$0\n");
```

Comment: so how can if select not known digits length in selected pattern?

Comment: That depends on the regex engine you use.

Answer (score 1):

You are not able to use variable length look behinds in most implementations of regex.  However, you should be able to solve this without the look behind:

```
# Match your string in a group
/(Art\.\s\d+\.)/g

# Replace and append a new line to $1 match group
$1\n
```

Example: http://regex101.com/r/fW5jO7

We don't know what language you are using, but a PHP implementation:

```
preg_replace('/(Art\.\s\d+\.)/', "$1\n", $text);
```

Answer (score 0):

In perl:

```
for (<DATA>) {
  print;
  print("\n") if (/Art\. \d+\./);
}
__DATA__
whatver
stuff
Art. 83.
123 456 789
Art. 3.
987 654 321
more
stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

Use grouping instead of lookbehind

```
(Art..\d\d.)(.)
```

and then get group 2

Answer (score 0):

A Notepad++ solution:

Find what: `^(Art\.\s*\d+\.)`
Replace with: `$1\n`

May be you want crlf, so use: Replace with:`$1\r\n`